# How does STA works with input ports? Assembly i8080

Tags: assembly, microprocessors

I have such a task: check the numbers in ports from 00 to 07 on negative, positive and zero. Output the number of negative numbers in port 00, zeroes in port 01 and positive numbers in port 02

Here is the code:

```
org 0
.startup
mvi c,8
in 00

ana a
jm minusCheck
jz zeroCheck
jp plusCheck

minusCheck:
inr e
jmp counter

zeroCheck:
inr b
jmp counter

plusCheck:
inr d
jmp counter

counter:
inr h
mov a,h
cmp c
jz output
sta 3
jmp 2

output:
mov a,e
out 00
mov a,b
out 01
mov a,d
out 02

hlt
```

I can`t understand how STA in this case works? So at the first itteration of the code we check the number in the 00 input port when the line STA is done and JMP directs us on the adress 0002 we are checking the 01 input port and these operations continues to the 07 input port. Can you explain me how does it changes the input ports?

Comment: It is impossible do indirect addressing on ports. You must use direct instruction `in addr`. Are you sure that you have check  IO address, not memory address? If really yes, you must have in your code 8 times `in` instruction  and add some conditional jumps regarding counter register (like switch statement in C). `In 00` will always read port 0. Also you don't have initialized many registers in your code. And question is why you make this code in this way if you don't understand how can work?

Comment: @PeterPlesník I have already understood how it works. So the command `in addr` is a 2 byte command where 1 byte is for `in` command and the second byte is for `addr` opperand. And as I have my `in` command in the 0002 memory cell the 0003 memory cell contains its `addr` opperand.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Self modifying code.